# Animating UISwitch 'onTintColor' property

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm trying to animate a color change of the switch's `onTintColor` property. When the animation occurs, the color changes immediately with no transition and the color section expands to a rectangle and then returns back to the 'clipped' rounded rectangle tint color area.

Here is a small video of this: https://giphy.com/gifs/2A0JVhZmKwUtqJiqOT/html5

I've tried using `UIView.animate(withDuration` and `UIView.transition`, but get the same result.

```
UIView.transition(with: multiplierSwitch, duration: 0.7, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        self.mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.red
    }, completion: nil)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

---

**SOLUTION EDIT:** Using the `CATransition` class I could animate the transition between the different colors without the 'square extension' I was seeing before.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
transition.duration = 0.7
mySwitch.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
mySwitch.onTintColor = .red
```

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include the answer, you should add an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `CATransition` class I could animate the transition between the different colors without the 'square extension' I was seeing before.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
transition.duration = 0.7
mySwitch.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
mySwitch.onTintColor = .red
```